# Pushing Private package in Github Packages Nuget error

Tags: github-actions, github-packages

I am having a weird exception during publishing my nuget packages with Github actions

```
Run dotnet nuget push ./package/*.nupkg --api-key *** --skip-duplicate --no-symbols true
Pushing WayStation_Models.1.0.0.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<Organization>'...
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<Organization>/
  OK https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<Organization>/ 2209ms
Your package was pushed.
error: File does not exist (true).
```

Using nuget push successfully pushed the package (it exists on the repo!) but it still returns the File does not exist error and the pipeline shows failed.

Is this just a limitation of private repositories?

This is my auth and release job flow:

```
release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest    
    needs: build
    permissions: 
      packages: write
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' # only run job if on the main branch   
    
    steps:  
    #Push NuGet package to GitHub packages
    - name: Download nuget package artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: nugetPackage
        path: ./package
    - name: Setup .NET Core @ Latest
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 7.0.x
        source-url: ${{ secrets.GHPACKAGESURL }}
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}   
    - name: Push package to GitHub packages 
      run: dotnet nuget push ./package/*.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --skip-duplicate --no-symbols true
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by the parameter:

```
--no-symbols true
```

in

```
- name: Push package to GitHub packages        
  run: dotnet nuget push ./package/*.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --skip-duplicate --no-symbols true
```